# setSelectedChild on ExpandableListView not working

Tags: android

I would like to have the ability when selecting a group, that after it expands it automatically selects the first child.  My code is as follows:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ExpandableListView listView = (ExpandableListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list);

    listView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            listView.setSelectedChild(groupPosition, 0, true);
        }
    });

    getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, this);
}
```

My adapter for my list is a `CursorTreeAdapter`.  I'm assuming that `setSelectedChild(...)` is not working because when `myCursorTreeAdapter.getChildrenCursor(...)` gets called, it loads the cursor of children in the background, and `setSelectedChild(...)` is getting called PRIOR to the `myCursorTreeAdapter.getChildrenCursor(...)` finishing (so there are no children YET when the call is being made).

I have tried to look for some sort Listener on the CursorTreeAdapter (to know when the children finish getting loaded)... but there does not seem to be any ability to add a Listener there.

Does anyone have any ideas on solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a custom `CursorTreeAdapter` and

Override `onGroupExpanded()`to call the global listView's `setSelectedChild` method.

Or you could set the child as selected inside of `bindChildView`.

Both of these would however require you to write and override all necessary the methods.